# Do Grant permissions Cascade?

Tags: oracle, security

This is hopefully a quick one, i'm new to oracle so need to check something before it bites me on the posterior

Ok i have a function that modifies a table

if i give the user permission to execute the function do they also need permission to update and insert in the table or is the fact they are approved to use the function enough?

the reason i ask is that the users need to edit these tables but only via approved functions which perform complex validation that can't be done easily via constraints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you define your procedure, specifically the [`AUTHID` property](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#i18574):

> The `AUTHID` property of a stored PL/SQL unit affects the name resolution and privilege checking of SQL statements that the unit issues at run time.

By default the procedures are created with a `AUTHID` value of `DEFINER` (*definer's right*) ,the functions are executed as if the caller were temporarily given the rights of the definer.

With a value of `CURRENT_USER`, the `AUTHID` property will make the procedures check the privileges of the caller at run-time.

In your case, the scenario you describe would fit with the property value of `DEFINER` (the default): the users will only be able to call the procedures and functions without direct access to the underlying tables. A similar scenario is described in the documentation:

> **Scenario:** Suppose that you must create an API whose procedures have unrestricted access to its tables, but you want to prevent ordinary users from selecting table data directly, and from changing it with INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.
>
> **Solution:** In a special schema, create the tables and the procedures that comprise the API. By default, each procedure is a DR unit, so you need not specify AUTHID DEFINER when you create it. To other users, grant the EXECUTE privilege, but do not grant any privileges that allow data access.